# Вызов функции из массива в php

Tags: php, callback

Приветствую!

Есть некоторый метод класса, который я вызываю:

```
View::setMetaCallback("\+rnd_number\+",function(){
  $var = rand(0,99);
  echo $var."\r\n";
  return "{$var}";
});
```

И сам, небольшой код класса View:

```
public static function setMetaCallback($str,$callback){
            self::$metaCallback[][0] = $str;
            self::$metaCallback[][1] = $callback;
        }

public static function fillMetaCallback($str){
            foreach (self::$metaCallback as $key => $val) {
                $past = call_user_func($val[1]);
                //$str = preg_replace("%".$val[0]."%im",$past,$str);

            }
            return $str;
        }
```

В моем контексте задачи, я должен обработать строку, таким образом:
найти подстроку в некотором тексте совпадающую с **self::$metaCallback[n][0]**, и вставить вместо нее то, что вернет **self::$metaCallback[n][1]**

Пока, что я бьюсь над тем, что бы без проблем вызвать функцию из массива.
Нашел способ работающий:

```
call_user_func($val[1]);
```

...но функция вроде бы работает.
...но сообщения я вижу на странице, вот такие:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in <b>...\view.php</b> on line <b>183</b><br />
46
```

*46 — это результат работы функции*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше мне поступить, что бы этих ошибок не возникало?
Как правильно вызывать функции, которые передается параметрами или в массиве?

Comment: А ошибка у вас выскакивает по причине создания тут `self::$metaCallback[][0] = $str; self::$metaCallback[][1] = $callback;` двух элементов массива, с индексами `[0][0]` - строка, `[1][1]` - функция, и т.д.

Comment: О! Спасибо за дельное замечание, я этот момент действительно упустил из виду!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может лучше так:

```
public static function setMetaCallback($str,$callback){
    self::$metaCallback[$str] = $callback;
}

public static function fillMetaCallback($str){
    if (isset(self::$metaCallback[$str])) {
        $str = call_user_func(self::$metaCallback[$str])
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Вернет или строку со входа, если нет элемента с таким ключем `$str` или результат работы функции хранимой в элементе с этим ключем.

Comment: Это хороший вариант. Я проверю чуть позже его работоспособность. Благодарю вас, за ответ. После проверки отпишусь и возможно приму ваш вариант.

Comment: Идеально! Благодарю вас, за помощь!